# "uninitialized constant" routing error using Clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, clearance

I'm using Clearance for authentication and am attempting to set the root depending on whether the user is logged in or not. Logging in, logging out and creating/deleting users works fine.

I'm following this [article from Thoughtbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/22605580334/constrain-yourself) where I've added a constraint to my route.

```
# Logged in user
root to: "dashboard#index", constraints: Clearance::SignedInConstraint`

# Visitor
root to: "home#index"
```

And I've also created signed_in_constraint.rb in /lib/clearance which performs the check:

```
module Clearance
  class SignedInConstraint
    def self.matches?(request)
      request.env[:clearance].signed_in?
    end
  end
end
```

If I open up rails console and check Clearance, I get no errors so it is loading the Clearance module but not SignedInConstraint from lib.

```
rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)    
irb(main):001:0> Clearance
=> Clearance
irb(main):002:0> Clearance::SignedInConstraint
NameError: uninitialized constant Clearance::SignedInConstraint
```

I've also restarted my server (running Anvil and PostgresApp) multiple times as per [this ticket](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/196) on the Github repo.

Using Rails 4 on Ruby 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints are built into Clearance now. You can do stuff like the following:

```
constraints Clearance::Constraints::SignedIn.new { |user| user.admin? } do
  root to: 'admin'
end

constraints Clearance::Constraints::SignedIn.new do
  root to: 'dashboard'
end

constraints Clearance::Constraints::SignedOut.new do
  root to: 'marketing'
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dan - I did see that in the docs but I get `ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'`. Is any additional logic required?

Comment: It appears this (no duplicate names) has purposely been built into Rails 4. I've now named the routes using ':as' and it's working correctly. Thanks for your help. [Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393)